# VS C# project will only run if its inside the original build directory

Tags: c#

i have a somewhat big project, its a background application for windows and i was testing it out on my other computer. I copied and pasted the .exe from the debug folder and ran it. I opened task manager and it would stay running for a few secs until it stopped responding and quit.

I then decided to move the whole VS folder for that project and ran the .exe while it was inside and it worked perfect. Normally just copying the .exe to a usb or something and running it will work perfect. I am also using 3 external librarys which are located in the debug folder too, is that why it only runs while the .exe is in the folder with them? Would it be possible to kind of finish my project into 1 .exe file to use?

If anyone has any ideas on why this is happening, id appriciate it :)

Comment: The exe alone will not work. You need to copy all the files in your bin/Release folder or all files not containing vshost from your debug folder.

Comment: "is that why it only runs while the .exe is in the folder with them" - yes, they're loaded at execution time. There *are* ways of merging assemblies together, but I'd recommend against using them unless you really need to. Why do you want a single exe file?

Comment: dammit that sucks, its just alot eaiser than a single exe file + 3 library files

Comment: It is most definitely *not* easier for the end user. It creates what we call "dll-hell"